# Is there a way to grab event state before redrawing with onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm using [React-Dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) for a file uploader. It takes an `onDropAccepted` prop. Which returns both the accepted files and the event from the onDrop.

My `onDropAccepted` function looks as follows.

```
export const onDropAccepted = onChange => (acceptedFiles, event) => {
  onChange(acceptedFiles);
  event?.target?.form?.requestSubmit();
};
```

My issue is that the event gets redrawn after calling the onChange function and does not have the properties I am calling with to call `requestSubmit`. The event contains the correct information before onChange. The onChange handler is from [React-JsonSchema-Form](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Wasn't able to find the implementation but the functionality is needed in how my form is implemented. Is there a way to maintain the `event.form.requestSubmit()` and call onChange?

The submission calls an `onSubmitHandler` and runs some logic. My goal is to run the onChange function then just call submit.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Sidenote: perhaps time to use more modern JS: `event?.target?.form?.requestSubmit();`, no need for `&&` "cleverness" anymore. Especially if you target modern browsers, or use babel.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Appreciate that